# PHP - Updating form data. (on same page)

Tags: php, forms, csv

I need to be able to update my form data once the submit button is pressed on the same page.

I have a csv file. And at the moment, I have worked out how to edit data inside it, and save it in the csv file (through a form). 
-(I have attached the main code below, but even any suggestions would be helpful)

The form and php execution is on the same page, but once the user edits the values and presses submit, the data goes back to the original data. So it updates in the csv file, but not in the form.

This is the form:

```
for ($i=0; $i<200; $i++) {
    if(empty($SearchResults[$i][0]) == false){ //If its full

    ?>
    <form method="post" action="">

  Full Name: <input name = "Name2" type="text" value="<?php echo $SearchResults[$i][0] ?>"/>

  Weight (kg): <input name="Weight2" type="number" value="<?php echo $SearchResults[$i][1] ?>"/>

 Weight of belongings (kg): <input name="WeightOfBelongings2" type="number"value="<?php echo $SearchResults[$i][2] ?>"/>

  <input name="submit" type="submit" />
  </form>

    <?php

        $i++;

    }else if (empty($SearchResults[$i][0]) == true){ //If it is empty 

    $i =201;



    }
}
```

This is what happens when the submit button is pressed:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {


    $FullName = $_POST['Name2'];
    $Weight = $_POST['Weight2'];
    $WeightOfBelongings = $_POST['WeightOfBelongings2'];

//Creates a new felon from the class in felen.php and assigns it to this variable $Felon
$Felen = new felen;

//This refers to a function in the class Felen. From this information it calculates the costs, ammounts etc. And saves it to a variable that can be called.
$Felen -> CreateFelen($FullName, $Weight, $WeightOfBelongings);

//This is a for loop that checks when there is an avaliable line to put the data into.
if ($FullName != "") {
    $i = 0;
for ($i=0; $i<200; $i++) {


    if(empty($csv[$i][0]) == false){ //If its full
    if($csv[$i][0] == $_POST['Name2']){

        //its only printing it if it is in the first row?

        $csv[$i][0] = $FullName;
        $csv[$i][1] = $Weight;
        $csv[$i][2] = $WeightOfBelongings;
        $csv[$i][3] = $Felen->FelenTotalWeight;
        $csv[$i][4] = $Felen->UnassembliumRequired;
        $csv[$i][5] = $Felen->ReassembliumRequired;
        $csv[$i][6] = $Felen->CostOfUnassemblium;
        $csv[$i][7] = $Felen->CostOfReassemblium;
        $csv[$i][8] = $Felen->TotalCostOfJourney;

        $i = 201;


    }
    }

  } 



//Saves the previous data and new changes to the csv file
//This opens to file as a write file
$fp = fopen('data.csv', 'w');


//This takes the array that has had data ddded to it and adds it to the file

foreach ($csv as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

//This closes the file
fclose($fp);


}
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: why is there another $i++; in for loop?

Comment: Hmmm not sure... haha.  I know it works though. I will have a look tonight if I remember.